# Настройка сети для VirtualBox

Tags: сеть, debian, virtualbox, nat

У меня на компе стоит Dеbian, на нем стоит Virtualbox, на виртуалке freebsd. Как настроить сеть и интернет через nat?

Answer (score 2):

Запускаем виртуалку, только не запускаем пока ОС. Потом кликаем сверху Settings -> Network  После того как вкладка Network открыта  по умолчанию будет выбран первый адаптер(Adapter 1) должна стоять галочке Enabled Network Adapter. В пункте Attached to: выбираем либо Bridge adapter (это значит мы виртуалке FreeBSD должны будем присвоить свой ипе), если NAT по дефолту оставить, то при загрузке он автоматом должен выдать ипе.

P.S. но не думаю на FreeBSD будет автоматом выдан ипе если не поднять DHCP сервер на Debian. Поэтому лучше прописать ручками ипе(Не забудьте они должны быть из одной подсети).

Comment: Да на дебиане у меня сеть DHCP  ну автоматом настрилась, я не могу понять как это из одной под сети вот у меня ip 192.168.1.2 - у компа 192,168,1,1 - основной шлюз ну модем навернов вертуальке там  Settings -> Network  стоит айпи 192,168,56,1 ну да когда ставлю  Сетевой мост (Bridge)и в Freebsd  айпи вписываю 192,168,1,3 и шлюз 192,168,1,1  работает и сеть и интернета вот в NAT  сеть подымается  тока по DHCP  и там айпи стоят 10.10.10.1  а как самому все присвоить вручную и что бы сеть была и интернет я не догоняю пожалуйста скажите :)

Comment: Не понял немного последнего вопроса?! Изменить вручную где в DHCP сервере?

Comment: Если да, то зайдите в конфиг dhcp сервера и поменяйте подсеть вручную    #nano /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf либо тут    #nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf-    # нужно изменить согласно вашим настройкам    subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {      range 192.168.1.200 192.168.1.253;      option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;    # адрес шлюза, который может быть другим    # (для доступа в интернет, например)      option routers 192.168.1.1;    # используемый dns      option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.3;    }